# Lightning Component for Visualforce issue for Guest User

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, for

In answer to this thread - [Expose Lightning App via Sites (and embed via Canvas)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/72900/expose-lightning-app-via-sites-and-embed-via-canvas/105529#105529) - Doug has mentioned that there is bug for guest user when using LC4VF.
"*There is currently an issue (actively being worked on) when you try to leverage LC4VF from a VF page running under Sites/Communities. There is a related issue when attempting to use LO with a guest user that we are also working on.*"

I have W16 edition org, where I have created public site page which uses lightning component.

However, the page when accessed shows nothing and there are no script error either.

Does anyone knows if the issue has been resolved ?

Thanks,
Dayanand